# Define which elements a JS function will affect from CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I've been using a jQuery plug-in called Dot Dot Dot to put ellipsis on certain text elements that may overflow. I don't particularly want to apply this to every element in the DOM, so I've been putting the class ".ellipsis" on things that may overflow.  The other option I have is to select the items with CSS style selectors in JS, and not add the class to the items.

BUT, I'm trying to separate all of the styling from my HTML templates, so what I would like to do is select the elements in the Stylesheet, and have the jQuery plugin affect only those items. Something like this:

**In Stylesheet:**

```
main fig > figcaption (just an example selector, doesn't matter) {  
    Ellipsis: true;  
}
```

**In JS:**

```
$("select items with ellipsis: true").dotdotdot(do its thing);
```

**The questions:**
How bad is it to put unofficial css properties on objects, will it even work?

Can I then select these objects with jQuery?

Comment: You know you can use [`text-overflow`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) CSS property to do this

Comment: Having a class attribute that has no css is not great, but it is a lot better than going with non-standard CSS. As it is not standard, it's fucntionality can not be garunteed across browsers now or in the future. Your best option is to work out what it the common feature that ties the elements that are candidates for shotening and use that. E.g are they articles, side bar tiems ets.

Comment: I dont't think text-overflow will quite do what I want to do, but definitely worth a mention. I want to alter the title tag of anything that does overflow to the text that is overflowed.

The class attribute isn't really the problem, as like I said, I can already use CSS style selectors in jQuery.  The problem is that that selectors would ultimately live in the HTML template anyways, and I really want them to be in the CSS file. Its a separation of concerns issue. The HTML doesn't, and shouldn't know if the layout may cause overflow.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/), I would use the `callback`option to change the title if ellipsis is added. I think providing a more concrete example of what you are trying to achive would be usefull. Add a snippet to your question using the <> button in the editor

Comment: What you're trying will not work. jQuery selectors can't match styles from stylesheets (except for special cases like `:visible` and `:hidden`).

Comment: @Jon P:
I do actually have dot dot dot set up using callback already as you suggest.  The problem is simply where to put the code. But if there is not way to do it, I guess I'll just have to add an external JS file for styling, and manage that along with the CSS.